# Discord.py | Как переотправить картинку

Tags: discord.py

Нужно как-то сделать так что при отправке сообщение + картинка боту в лс он их переотправлял в другой канал, как переотправить сообщение я знаю, а вот с картинкой нет(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel('channel_id')
    if not message.guild:
        if message.attachments:
            msg = await _channel.fetch_message(message.id)
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=message.content).set_thumbnail(url=msg.attachments[0].url))
```

Comment: А можно сделать так что-бы отправлялось в ембед?

Comment: Да, исправил, отметьте вопрос как решение, если вам это помогло